# Can Cognito form work offline and be embedded in iPad app?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can Cognito form work offline? I need a form that works both online and offline. When offline, user can still fill in the form. Data is stored in the app and be sent to database once the iPad is connected to internet again.

Can Cognito form be embedded in iPad app?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, with a bit of work.

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) uses pure JavaScript, CSS and HTML5 to enable a rich consistent and responsive experience across devices.  You can copy the output for the public form links to create forms and use local storage in the browser or even native phone storage to save form data as JSON to save work in progress.  Please submit a support request for more details, as this is not a documented capability of Cognito Forms.